# How to remove the city labels when using Mapkit on Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, mapkit, mkmapview

I would like to remove all the labels such as the city names that comes with default when I use the Mapkit on xcode i.e I would be loading a plain MapView with the continents but no information about the cities/countries name. Is there any way I could do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to modify maps look into some of the custom mapping SDK's, like CloudMade based on OpenStreetMap tiles:

http://cloudmade.com/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the data coming from Google cannot be modified, and I believe that the license you agree to when using MapKit specifically disallows modifying the maps.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make your own overlays that would obscure the Google data, though it would still be fetched behind the scenes as far as I can tell. I'm trying to find out how to stop loading Google's maps and will let you know if that's possible.

Look at the TileMap demo from Apple for info on how to display your overlays.